# Why doesn't both these codes give the same output?

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing, syntax

So I want draw a field (of array strings) with obstacles and free spaces. `"+"` are the obstacles and free spaces are just `""`. And if we have a free space, I want it replaced by `"*"`. I will choose **one** specific element of that 2d array that equals `""` and that will be replaced by `"1"`.

My question isn't as long as it seems, you could ignore the 2 codes below. Here is summary, if unclear, please read to the end:

Why aren't these things equal to each other?

```
if(field[i][j]==field[5][1]){
  System.out.print("1");
}
```

and

```
if(i==5 && j==1){
   System.out.print("1");
}
```

---

First code doesn't work. That specific array element here will be `field[5][1]` which I want replace by `1`:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] field = {{"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "" , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,""  , ""  , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , ""  ,""  , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , ""  , ""  , ""  ,"+" , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , ""  , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "+" , "+"}};
        int x = field.length;

        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<field[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(field[i][j]);

                if(field[i][j] != "+"){
                    if(field[i][j]==field[5][1]){
                        System.out.print("1");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}

Output:
+++++++
+++++1+
++++11+
+++11++
+111+++
+1+++++
+++++++
```

Second code works as desired:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] field = {{"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "" , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,""  , ""  , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , ""  ,""  , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , ""  , ""  , ""  ,"+" , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , ""  , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "+" , "+"},
                            {"+" , "+" , "+" , "+" ,"+" , "+" , "+"}};
        int x = field.length;

        for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<field[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(field[i][j]);

                if(field[i][j] != "+"){
                    if(i==5 && j==1){
                        System.out.print("1");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}

Output: 
+++++++
+++++*+
++++**+
+++**++
+***+++
+1+++++
+++++++
```

Comment: @Berger no - all of these strings are literals, so you can compare them by `==`.

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title: accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are obviously different:

```
if(field[i][j]==field[5][1]){
```

Is true if `field[i][j]` is `""` - and there are lots of array elements equal to that.

```
if(i==5 && j==1){
```

is true if `i == 5` and `j == 1` - which is only true at 1 position.

---

It should be noted that the first approach is not a reliable way to compare strings: it is only because of the way that you construct `field` that the code currently behaves as it does. In general, you should use `field[i][j].equals(field[5][1])`. See [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(field[i][j]==field[5][1]){
  System.out.print("1");
}
```

This this compares value of field[5][1] which is equals to "" and every field that has value "" prints number "1". This code doesn't check the field position but compares values.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (field[i][j] == field[5][1]) {
  System.out.print("1");
}
```

checks whether the current field's value is equal to the value of `field[5][1]` (that's `""` in your case). As you can see, the first output marks every `""` from `field` with a `1`.

```
if (i==5 && j==1) {
   System.out.print("1");
}
```

checks whether the current position is 5,1. Values of `field` are not considered.

Answer (score 0):

if(i==5 && j==1) is true for only one case,
 if(field[i][j]==field[5][1]) is true for all the case with the same value than field[5][1]. ("")

If your question is "why == work between two different string?"

The cause is an optimisation of the compilator, who will create a constante for each identical string , so when == compare the reference of two string with different (i,j), it's in fact the same String Object, so it's true.